# Api goslate http error 429: Too many request

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

tengo una cuenta bot de twitter que saluda a los nuevos seguidores y he intentado hacer que les salude en su idioma mediante el siguiente sistema: El bot detecta un nuevo seguidor (sabe que es nuevo porque no está en FILE_SEGUIDORES), recoge el texto de su biografía, con la función detect de goslate detecta qué idioma es, y con la función translate traduce "Bienvenido" al idioma antes detectado, después sube el tweet dando la bienvenida, etc.

```
import goslate
print("Saludando a los nuevos seguidores...")
seguidores = get_seguidores(FILE_SEGUIDORES)
seguidores_actuales = api.followers(count = 50)

for seguidor_actual in seguidores_actuales:
    if seguidor_actual.screen_name in seguidores:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            print("Nuevo follower amante de las nutrias: @" + seguidor_actual.screen_name + "\n")
            try:
                bio = seguidor_actual.description
                gs = goslate.Goslate()
                idioma = gs.detect(bio)
                bienvenido = gs.translate("Bienvenido", idioma)
                posicion = get_numero()
                api.update_with_media(filename = get_foto(posicion), status = bienvenido + u", @" + seguidor_actual.screen_name + u" ❤️")
                guardar_seguidor(FILE_SEGUIDORES, seguidor_actual.screen_name)
            except Exception as inst:
                print("NO se pudo traducir el saludo")
                print(inst)
                posicion = get_numero()
                api.update_with_media(filename = get_foto(posicion), status = u"Welcome, @" + seguidor_actual.screen_name + u" ❤️")
                guardar_seguidor(FILE_SEGUIDORES, seguidor_actual.screen_name)
        except Exception as inst:
            print(type(inst))
            print(inst.args)
            print(inst)
```

Todo funciona bien, el bot actualmente está respondiendo a los nuevos seguidores con "Welcome...", pero JAMÁS ha saludado a ninguno en su idioma, debido a que siempre me sale el error 429. ¿Cómo es posible que me salte este error si apenas habré usado la api para hacer 2-3 pruebas?
Hasta donde creo saber, la api tiene un límite de 100 peticiones por hora, así que dejé el código durante un par de horas como estaba antes (sin utilizar la api de goslate) y cuando volví a colocar la parte de goslate me volvía a saltar el error 429. No le encuentro el sentido, ¿por qué me sale que mando muchas peticiones cuando sólo mando una en varias horas?.

Comment: Es sensible al tiempo entre cada petición, no es lo mismo 2 peticiones separadas por 30 segundos a 2 peticiones separadas por 5 ms, al inicializar, debes dar un lapso de tiempo bastante considerable (como si fueras un humano, en algunos casos)entre cada petición. el límite máximo por hora no es relevante cuando el sistema detecta un "posible ataque".
Saludos